# Как создать пиксель закрашенный цветом?

Tags: java, android

Как создать пиксель закрашенный цветом?
Необходимо на activity создать пиксель, закрашенный цветом. Самым простым способом.

Comment: Согласен, тогда Java.

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю, зачем вообще такое может понадобиться, ибо на современных дисплеях рассмотреть все будет очень проблематично, но сделать можно. Просто необходимо в Layout'e создать элемент View, а вместо общепринятых размеров в dp указать все напрямую в пикселях px.

```
<View
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_width="1px"
        android:layout_height="1px"/>
```

Comment: Это необходимо для создания эффекта движения. Представьте, что у вас есть некоторый Seekbar, при движении которого на вашем активити появляется некоторые огоньки из пикселей.